# Perl - convert ASCII art to use x operator

Tags: code-golf, tips, perl

I would like to convert ASCII art to something that takes less bytes. I have string like this:

```
my $string = '                ██   ████   █';
```

And I would convert this to something like this:

```
print "█" x 1."█" x 1."█" x 1"█" x 1"█" x 1;
```

So I would write this in one line and convert to using `x` operator. How can achieve this?

Comment: Welcome to PPCG! I have added the code-golf tag since questions here require a winning criteria. Generally questions here allow any language to compete (you can always say you are keen to see Perl solutions), so I'd suggest that (an alternative would be to fit this to the [tips](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/tags/tips/info) category but I think it fits better as a normal golf question). EDIT: I see Shaggy also added tips now - let's see where we go :)

Comment: Don't you mean `print " " x 16."█" x 2." " x 3."█" x 4." " x 3."█" x 1;`?

Comment: @JonathanAllan even if it was intended as a challenge, it's *horribly* underspecified.

Comment: @StephenLeppik I don't think it was and agree. It could probably be made into one though!

Comment: @JonathanAllan Isn't it just asking for run-length encoding?

Comment: @Adám uh, probably.

Comment: XY problem? How can you be sure that RLE is the shortest way?

Comment: [This was first posted on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50107417/perl-convert-ascii-art-to-use-x-operator)